# How to redirect resources with A record

Tags: cpanel

How can i show resources from sub.domain2.com on sub.domain1.com.

I tried configuring A record with sub.domain1.com to point sub.domain2.com IP.

I'm using a WHM, but when i type URL: sub.domain1.com on browser, 
i get the below image error.

How to configure this on cPanel/WHM to make this work?

[image: Image Error]

Answer (score 1):

After making a change in your DNS records and adding a new record that points to a server the services that are running on that IP-address usually need to be (re-) configured to deal correctly with requests using the new DNS name (unless the default service behavior is also suitable for the new DNS name).

For instance a web server running plain http and only one website will usually display that website regardless of the hostname used to access the web server, but for a web server running multiple virtual hosts and  HTTPS you will need to both request a new TLS certificate with the  domain name AND you need to either create a new virtual host entry, or add that DNS name as a secondary/alias name to a  existing virtual host.